# How can I set one subview below another subview in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

```
var mainStack = new UIStackView();
mainStack.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Leading;
mainStack.Spacing = 10;
mainStack.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
mainStack.Frame = new CGRect(10,10,Frame.Width - 30,Frame.Height - 100);


var mainStack1 = new UIStackView();
mainStack1.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center;
mainStack1.Spacing = 10;
mainStack1.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
mainStack1.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, Frame.Width - 30, Frame.Height - 200);

this.AddSubview(mainStack);

this.AddSubview(mainStack1);
```

These are the two subviews i have used, I want to insert one subview below to another subview. I faced a problem that the two subviews are override.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to change the order you add the views. The last one added will be on top, so if the issue is just with the exact code you shared, just reverse the order of adding the subviews:

```
this.AddSubview(mainStack1);
this.AddSubview(mainStack);
```

Also you can bring a subview to the front with (assuming `this` is a view):

```
this.BringSubviewToFront(mainStack);
```

Or you can adjust the Z-Order using the Layer property of a view:

```
mainStack1.Layer.ZPosition = 0;
mainStack.Layer.ZPosition = 1;
```

UIView.Layer with higher z positions will appear in front of UIView.Layer with lower z positions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the second view not displaying on view :( –